# Aurora MySql DB backup size increased drastically

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am running Aurora MySql Engine version 5.6.10a in the production environment. Automated DB snapshot size on 9th May was 120 GB and this snapshot size increased by 27 GB to 147 GB. I have checked that DB size did not increase even by 1 GB. I looked on the internet for the reason why this happened but got nothing.

Graph for snapshot size for the last two weeks as:

[image]

It's pretty consistent till 9th May and after 10th May. Does anyone have insight into this issue?

The rate of increase in DB size:

[image]

VolumeBytesUsed Graph:
[image]

Your help will be much appreciated!!

Thanks,
Mayurkumar

Answer (score 1):

There is bug in aurora storage provisioning , we have also faced the same issue for one of our client.
In our case the storage grew from 17gb to 22000 gb in 15 days where db size was just 16gb. We were charged a lot for that period , you can connect to aws support for the resolution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

How were you checking you snapshot size? One possibility is that may have configured daily backups or so, which might be the reason why your total backup size is growing. Would love to help out more if you can provide more details on the number of snapshots, how you were checking the size of the cluster and the snapshot etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Karthik. I have added an image of how the DB snapshot size increased. It was jumped from 120 GB to 148 GB in just one day. I have verified that there was no actual data increase in DB. any idea?

Comment: How did you verify the data size? And the screenshot of the snapshot size you posted - are those the sizes of daily snapshots? Can you share the image for the cloudwatch metric - VolumeBytesUsed ?

Comment: I checked the all table sizes after the increased the DB snapshot size and before that. The rate of increase in data was regular. Yes, The second image shows the daily snapshot sizes. I have shared the chart of VolumeBytesUsed as you mentioned in your comment. Thanks.

Comment: So, if I'm reading this right, your VolumeBytesUsed matches with the snapshot size. The only concern that you have at the moment is the difference between the size you calculated vs the metric - is that correct? If yes, then can you share as much details as possible on how you calculated the DB size? VolumeBytesUsed is the authoritative metric emitted by Aurora on the distributed volume's size. There could be differences in the way you see size versus Aurora. A simple example is - Aurora does not shrink volumes if you delete a lot of data after expanding a volume.

Comment: I used this query to calculate my DB size: SELECT table_schema "DB Name", ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB" FROM information_schema.tables GROUP BY table_schema;

Comment: Data size is different from Volume size (and hence snapshot size). Aurora is a backed by a distributed storage volume, and hence your data storage formula is not the right mechanism to evaluate size of snapshot (or costs involved). There usually wont be a nig difference between traditional data size and volume size, but like I mentioned, there are many intricacies in the internals that might result is a different volume size. In short, I don't think there is an issue here, just that you've been comparing to different items. If you think thats a good explanation, I'll post a concise answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, I got it that, I was comparing two different things but why there is a suddenly increased amount of the snapshot size itself ~27GB in a single day. If you had already explained this then, I am sorry but, I didn't get it.

Comment: Did you insert and delete a lot of data around that time? If not, then sorry, I don't have a good explanation for why it had a spike of 27GB in one day without you doing anything to the DB.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. No, not a large amount of data insertion on that day. I hope it would be but, I am sure it's not. and there is no point of deletion so.. Thanks again..